# Multiple Menus for a Single Business Vendor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

we're trying to create a list of menu that can be displayed on our site like in the image. We'd like the menu items to change when we select different tabs. How can this be done? We're kind of new to coding here. Thanks in advance.

[image: Creating a menu]

Comment: Please note that Java != JavaScript, also take a look at jQueryUI tabs

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy first i suggest you to read about jQuery Tabs.You can also use this code.
Just include jQuery library to your page can paste this code you will get what you want.

HTML Code

```
<div id="tabs-container">
<ul class="tabs-menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
        <p>This is Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
        <p>This is Tab2 </p>

    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        <p>This is Tab3 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
        <p>This is Tab4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script Code is

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

CSS Code is

```
.tab-content {
    display: none;
}

#tab-1 {
 display: block;   
}
```